# Pandas DateTime - convert string which can be "0" to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, zero

The column I work with looks like the following:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20220104 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 20220506 |
| 4 | 20220206 |

The date column is an "object" type, holding string values. Note that this column can hold "0" as value.

My code that is supposed to convert the string values to datetime:

```
def transform_column(data,spec)
    """
    data: the dataframe
    spec: date format I would like it to look like in the end
    """

    data = chunk[spec[1]].apply(str)
    data = pd.to_datetime(data, format=spec[2])

    return data.dt.strftime(spec[3])
```

The configuration looks something like this (so you have an idea of the format expected in the spec parameter):

> "COLUMN_NAME" : ["date", "COLUMN_NAME", "%Y%m%d", "%m/%d/%Y"]

I would like to ask for ideas how to solve the "0" strings in this data, so the conversion works on the correctly formatted strings, and puts NAN or Null or something where it is "0". What is the value that pd.to_datetime could work with better when it should be able to convert the entire column? Is it actually possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could try to run [`pd.to_datetime(..., errors=‘coerce’)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), which will return `NaT` for all dates which can not be parsed, which is also the correct data type.

Comment: Ah wow - I didn't notice that in the docs! Thank you a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `errors='coerce'` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), converting to strings is not necessary:

```
def transform_column(data,spec):
    """
    data: the dataframe
    spec: date format I would like it to look like in the end
    """

    data[spec[0]] = (pd.to_datetime(data[spec[0]], format=spec[2], errors='coerce')
                       .dt.strftime(spec[3]))
    return data



d = {"col" : ["date", "COLUMN_NAME", "%Y%m%d", "%m/%d/%Y"]}

df = transform_column(df,d['col'])
print (df)
   id        date
0   1  01/04/2022
1   2         NaN
2   3  05/06/2022
3   4  02/06/2022
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to string:

```
df1['date'] = df1['date'].astype(str)
df1['newD'] = df1['date'].str[:4] + '-' + df1['date'].str[5:6] + '-' + 
df1['date'].str[7:8]
```